# How to draw this situation and is the metal the same area as the wood?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

A rectangular tabletop consists of a piece of laminated wood bordered by a thin metal strip along its four edges. The surface area of the tabletop is x square feet, and the total length of the strip before it was attached was x feet. If the tabletop is 3 feet wide, what is its approximate length, in feet?

(A) 12 (B) 10 (C) 9 (D) 8 (E) 6

This problem I don't think is a big rectangle encompassing a smaller rectangle that's centered within itself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: "thin", presumably, means you can neglect it for the dimensions of the table. The table is all wood with surface area $x$ and perimeter $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to answer this question in the most general form possible and hopefully convey my line of reasoning as I approach this problem.

Looking at your question, we see four things outlined for us.

1. There is a rectangle.
2. The perimeter and square footage have the same value.
3. The width is 3 feet.
4. We are seeking the length.

Additionally, we know that the area of a rectangle is the product of the width and the length and the perimeter is the sum between double the width and double the length. Using this information, we can construct the following system of equations where $l$ is the length.

$$
perimeter=2(3)+2(l)
$$
$$
area=3l
$$

Since the perimeter and the area are the same, we can set these equations equal to each other.

$$
2(3)+2(l)=3(l)
$$

$$
6=l
$$

Therefore, the table has the length of 6 feet.